# Testing Angular requests

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js, sinon, chai, angular-mock

Having a problem figuring out how to test an $http request on a factory.

Basic factory:

```
angular.module('myServices', [])
    .factory('myFactory', function($http) {
        return {
            postLog: function(logData) {
                logData.newProperty = 'my new property';
                return $http.post('/log', logData);
            };
        };
    });
```

Now I want to test this to make sure I have added my `newProperty`.  I would like to be able to write a test like:

```
it('adds a new property before POSTing', function() {
    MyFactory.postLog({message: 'posting a log!'});
    // catch the request somehow
    expect(theRequest.data).to.have.property('newProperty');
});
```

My original thought was that `$httpBackend.expect` would give me access to the request, but it only seems to have a `.respond` method and nothing else:

```
var MyFactory, backend;

beforeEach(function() {
    module('exampleApp');

    inject(function($httpBackend, _myFactory_) {
        backend = $httpBackend;
        backend.expect('POST', '/log').???  // would be nice to have a `.request` method here or a parameter passed to `.respond`
        MyFactory = _myFactory_;
    });

});
```

So I tried setting up an `httpInterceptor` by doing the following:

```
var MyFactory, theRequest;

beforeEach(function() {
    module('exampleApp', function($provide, $httpProvider) {
        $provide.service('requestCatcher', function() {
            this.request = function(req) {
                console.log(req);
                request = req;

                return req;
            };
        });

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('requestCatcher');
    });

    inject(function(_myFactory_) {
        MyFactory = _myFactory_;
    });
});

it('adds a new property before POSTing', function() {
    MyFactory.postLog({message: 'posting a log!'});
    expect(theRequest.data).to.have.property('newProperty');
});
```

But the interceptor never actually fires (the log doesn't print to the log).  I'm kind of out of ideas for this one.

Maybe I'm violating some principle by adding new properties in the `postLog` method and that should be refactored out into its own method for testability?  Still, it would be really nice if there was a way to tap into the outbound request, even if it is going to get "caught" by a `$httpBackend.expect`.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of the fine folks on the Angularjs gitter.im:

```
$httpBackend.expect('POST', '/log').respond(function(method, url, data, headers) {
   var mockReturnData = [{...}, {...}];
   console.log(data); // this is the data that was sent to the endpoint
   return [200, mockReturnData];
});
```

Can not find this in [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend) anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but you should create your mocks in a `beforeEach()` function for versatility.

```
describe('MyFactory', function() {
    var $httpBackend, userMock, MyFactory;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, _MyFactory_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        MyFactory = _MyFactory_;

        userMock = {user: {id: 1, name: 'shy guy'}};
    }));

    it('should pass', function() {
       $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/path/to/your/endpoint').respond(userMock);

       MyFactory.postLog({message: 'whatever'});
       $httpBackend.flush(); // Will dump the test data from the endpoint we specified above.

       expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

**Whats going on here?**

- `expectGET` prepares the response data for when a url you specify is called in the test.
- `flush()` is the trigger for the response data to be dumped (since timing can be everything in certain scenarios).

Note that if you call `expectGET` and don't actually make a request to the specified url, the test will fail.

Keep testing! Super worth it :)